# iOS10: How to avoid memory leaks in a segue circle

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have 4 scenes in my project, and `page1` can segue(type is `show`) to `page2`, then can segue to `page3`, then to `page4`, then back to `page1`.

You understand that in 1 second from my storyboard:

[image]

The class of controller of these four scene is `ViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    static var count: Int = 1

    var id = count

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        ViewController.count += 1
        print("ViewController#\(id) inited.")
    }

    deinit {
        print("ViewController#\(id) deinited.")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("ViewController#\(id) loaded.")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("ViewController#\(id) appeared.")
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        print("ViewController#\(id) disappeared.")
    }

}
```

Then after I finished the segue circle(page1 > page2 > page3 > page4 > page1), it outputs:

```
ViewController#1 inited.
ViewController#1 loaded.
ViewController#1 appeared.
ViewController#2 inited.
ViewController#2 loaded.
ViewController#2 appeared.
ViewController#1 disappeared.
ViewController#3 inited.
ViewController#3 loaded.
ViewController#3 appeared.
ViewController#2 disappeared.
ViewController#4 inited.
ViewController#4 loaded.
ViewController#4 appeared.
ViewController#3 disappeared.
ViewController#5 inited.
ViewController#5 loaded.
ViewController#5 appeared.
ViewController#4 disappeared.
```

That's not what I wanted. I think there are 5 `ViewController`s in my heap(because no deinit called). Indeed, we just need 1 `ViewController` which is to control `page1`. What should I do to destroy 4 useless ViewController in the heap of my App?

Comment: You can change the codes that segue to page1 to make page1 the root view controller, that'll remove the entire stack of view controllers you have

Comment: they are still exist in heap because you use "show" for segue, show means i want the controller, keep it for me. if you don't  want them you can use 'Present Modally' instead of 'show' ant then dismiss the controller.

Comment: If I reached the first view controller by performing the segue that connect from page 4 to page 1, should I see the back (pop) button to let me back to the fourth page?

Comment: @AhmadF No, you shouldn't see the back button. Indeed, there is no back button in my pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Presenting/Dismissing

**NOTE:**

**If you are working with a navigation controller, you might want to check my answer about *[Pushing/Popping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014385/ios10-how-to-avoid-memory-leaks-in-a-segue-circle/41015891#41015891)*.**

---

The action of "Back To Page1" in the fourth View Controller-, should be similar to:

```
@IBAction func backToPage01Tapped(_ sender: Any) {
    presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Note that the reason of why the number of [presentingViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621430-presentingviewcontroller) are three, because it's the number of previous View Controllers for the fourth one.

If you have only two previous View Controllers, then you must chain backwards twice and call dismiss from two View Controllers back:

```
presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and so on...

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: @Sayakiss Welcome mate :) Hope it sounds logical to you and glad to help.

Comment: Not only did this not work for me, but the window returned to the view controller I just attempted to dismiss and I got a warning that I'm not supposed to dismiss a view controller while it's being presented (not on top).

Answer (score 2):

### Pushing/Popping

**NOTE:**

**This answer is *ONLY* valid if you embed a *Navigation Controller*, if not (as the this question's case), check my answer about *[Presenting/Dsimissing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014385/ios10-how-to-avoid-memory-leaks-in-a-segue-circle/41016798#41016798)*.**

---

I think that there are 2 ways to perform the "page4 to page1" segue:

- Somewhere in your code (I assume that it's in the action of "Back To Page1" button), you are calling `performSegue` method,

OR

- You directly <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + drag to the first ViewController.

If you followed the the *first way*, replace the code of `performSegue` method with `popToRootViewController` method, as follows:

```
// "backToPage01Tapped" is just an example, it should be your method's name...
@IBAction func backToPage01Tapped(_ sender: Any) {
    navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

If you followed the *second way*, go to storyboard, select the "page4 to page1" segue and delete it! Instead, add an IBAction to the button and let be similar to the code snippet above.

Mainly, for your case, I suggest to [popToRootViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621855-poptorootviewcontroller):

> Pops all the view controllers on the stack except the root view
>   controller and updates the display.

Seems that's exactly what are your trying to achieve.

Comment: I followed your advice, but I just find `navigationController` is `nil` in my case.  I think the reason for that is I don't embed my view into a navigation controller.

Comment: Our UI designer give me a design which are just some simple pages like in my example(no back button, no titles), so I don't use `navigationController`.

Comment: @Sayakiss that's right, it seems that there is no embed navigation controller, so navigation treated as "presenting" not "pushing - show".

Comment: But the problem is, when `navigationController` is `nil`, then `navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)` won't take effect. Just let me stay in Page4 and no segue happens.

Comment: Well, how the showing the next view controller animating looks like? is it from right to left (pushing)? or is it from bottom to top (presenting)?

Comment: Here is my [screen capture](http://g.recordit.co/6VDgQWgTve.gif), a more [smooth one](http://giphy.com/gifs/3oz8xvlQX6PWoUlhRe)

Comment: @Sayakiss This is presenting, popToRootViewController is not the case here :). I will add another answer for this case.

Comment: But I think it's `show` segue, at least the storyboard claims it is. You can check that by my [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgLqa.jpg).

Comment: In previous version of xcode, adding "show segues" without embed navigation controller causing to crash, now, it by default will be treated as a "show modally" segue.

Answer (score 1):

What you did is simply wrong, don't use forward segue to go back from 4 to 1, you have to use unwind segue, or just set vc 1 in your navigation controller's viewControllers array, if you dont have navigation controller, just call delegate to vc1 to dismiss it's presenting controller, or set rootViewController back to vc1

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to iOS development, and I just don't understand how to implement  `just call delegate to vc1 to dismiss it's presenting controller`. Could you please explain it in details, or give an example or an article?

Comment: The easiest way is probably use unwind, delegate is a bit harder to understand, you can read about unwind [here](http://ashishkakkad.com/2015/04/work-with-unwind-segue-in-swift-language-ios-8/) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend to do an `unwind segue` and return to a previous `view controller`'s latest state, and you want to deallocate a prior view controller, then you are essentially treating one of the later view controllers as a new `rootViewController`, and until you reassign the root view controller property on the `AppDelegate` that first view controller won't be deallocated due to the `rootViewController` having a strong reference to it.

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = VCTwo
```